# Avoid session id reuse asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, session-timeout, sessionid

I am using cookie based session by using `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie`.

Is there an easy go so that I can set the reuse of expired sessionId and each time when the session expires `ASP.NET` creates a new session id.

Thanks.

Comment: FormsAuthentication has nothing to do with session.  You can have an authenticated user without a session and you can have a session without an authenticated user.  The FormsAuthentication ticket that you are setting with the above line of code issues an encrypted cookie that contains login information (such as user name, expiration time).  The session cookie, which is not set by this line is a plain text cookie that contains the session Id that corresponds with the session on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You have to deal with a couple of different cases.  The first is when someone clicks on the logout button.  The second is when the session itself has expired (but no user action has occured).

In the second instance, forms authentication will automatically send you to the login page that you have defined in your web.config.

You could do something like the following

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        Response.Cookies.Add(CreateExpiredBlankCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId"));
        return View();
    }

    private HttpCookie CreateExpiredBlankCookie(string name)
    {
        var cookie = new HttpCookie(name, "");
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
        return cookie;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Session.Abandon() to prevent session reuse.

Because HTTP is stateless, there's no way you can know when the user has closed the browser.  But, you *can* put a logout button on every page and as part of your handling for the button, call Session.Abandon to prevent a third-party from reusing it.

Beyond that, require HTTPS and make sure your cookies also require HTTPS.

Comment: Am using 

FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            Session.Abandon();
in my logout event.

but it does not work

Comment: same session id is used.

Comment: Sounds like you should perhaps combine my answer with the one from @CtrlDot